# Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException

Tags: asp.net-core, insert

I have a comment table where it have a two foreign key(i.e Userid and postid). I was trying to insert data into comment table using these two foreign key but was unable to insert. This is my post table

```
public class Post
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string PostText { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime PostDate { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
  }
```

And this is my comment table

```
public class Comment
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CommentText { get; set; }
    public DateTime CommentTime { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser CommentBy { get; set; }
    public Post Posts { get; set; }
  }
```

Comment service

```
public void Save(Comment comment)
    {
      _context.Set<Comment>().Add(comment);
      _context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

And this is my controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public ObjectResult SaveComment([FromBody] Comment comment)
    {
      if (ModelState.IsValid)
      {
        try
        {
          _commentService.Save(comment);
          return Ok("comment saved");
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
          return BadRequest(e);
        }
      } else
      {
        return BadRequest("Model is not valid");
      }
    }
```

And the error is

> {Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_AspNetUsers'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.AspNetUsers'. The duplicate key value is (966fc417-8757-4bac-89b2-9975d4f2cd41).
>
> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Posts' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
>
> The statement has been terminated.

this is my api request[image]

Comment: How are you adding a user to the comment?

Comment: You should get ApplicationUser and Post instance from database then set value into comment object before save changes

Comment: @Marcel - I have updated my question please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that **you will also insert a new `comment.CommentBy` when you're inserting a brand new `comment`**:

```
// the `comment` here is constructed by model binding, which is a brand new entity
[HttpPost]
public ObjectResult SaveComment([FromBody] Comment comment)
{
    // ...
    _commentService.Save(comment); // save the brand new comment
    // ...
}
```

"A brand new comment" means this `Comment` entity and its related propreties are all `untracked`. When saving a brand new entity, `EF Core` will also create related entities for you automatically.

To avoid this behavior, you could mark the state of `comment.CommentBy` as `Unchanged`,

```
_context.Entry(comment.CommentBy).State= EntityState.Unchanged;
```

so that the EF Core will not create a new `CommentBy` (i.e. an `ApplicationUser`) for you. But be careful: you must make sure the `ApplicationUser` already exists.

The same goes `Post`.

Another approach is much safer. As suggested by @Khai Nguyen in the comment, you should get `ApplicationUser` and `Post` instance from database, so that the EF Core knows there's already a `ApplicationUser` and a `Post` within database and won't insert new `ApplicationUser` or `Post` for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will check it when I am at home

Comment: Thank you sir, it really helped me